# Vaadin login page issues

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am new to Vaadin UI development, please excuse me in case of any silly mistakes. can someone please help?

I am trying to build a login page using the link https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+a+simple+login+view mentioned in Vaadin website. But am getting error - com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException

There are 3 classes

1) for Login View
2) For Main View
3) A main class which navigates between above 2 view

1) The login view is as below:

`public abstract class SimpleLoginView extends CustomComponent implements View,
Button.ClickListener {`

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final String NAME = "login";

private final TextField user;

private final PasswordField password;

private final Button loginButton;

public SimpleLoginView() {
    setSizeFull();

    // Create the user input field
    user = new TextField("User:");
    user.setWidth("300px");
    user.setRequired(true);
    user.setInputPrompt("Your username (eg. joe@email.com)");
    user.addValidator(new EmailValidator(
            "Username must be an email address"));
    user.setInvalidAllowed(false);

    // Create the password input field
    password = new PasswordField("Password:");
    password.setWidth("300px");
    password.addValidator(new PasswordValidator());
    password.setRequired(true);
    password.setValue("");
    password.setNullRepresentation("");

    // Create login button
    loginButton = new Button("Login", this);

    // Add both to a panel
    VerticalLayout fields = new VerticalLayout(user, password, loginButton);
    fields.setCaption("Please login to access the application. (test@test.com/passw0rd)");
    fields.setSpacing(true);
    fields.setMargin(new MarginInfo(true, true, true, false));
    fields.setSizeUndefined();

    // The view root layout
    VerticalLayout viewLayout = new VerticalLayout(fields);
    viewLayout.setSizeFull();
    viewLayout.setComponentAlignment(fields, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    viewLayout.setStyleName(Reindeer.LAYOUT_BLUE);
    setCompositionRoot(viewLayout);
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // focus the username field when user arrives to the login view
    user.focus();
}

// Validator for validating the passwords
private static final class PasswordValidator extends
AbstractValidator<String> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PasswordValidator() {
        super("The password provided is not valid");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isValidValue(String value) {
        //
        // Password must be at least 8 characters long and contain at least
        // one number
        //
        if (value != null
                && (value.length() < 8 || !value.matches(".*\\d.*"))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getType() {
        return String.class;
    }
}

@Override
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

    //
    // Validate the fields using the navigator. By using validors for the
    // fields we reduce the amount of queries we have to use to the database
    // for wrongly entered passwords
    //
    if (!user.isValid() || !password.isValid()) {
        return;
    }

    String username = user.getValue();
    String password = this.password.getValue();

    //
    // Validate username and password with database here. For examples sake
    // I use a dummy username and password.
    //
    boolean isValid = username.equals("test@test.com")
            && password.equals("passw0rd");

    if (isValid) {

        // Store the current user in the service session
        getSession().setAttribute("user", username);

        // Navigate to main view
        getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(MainView.NAME);//

    } else {

        // Wrong password clear the password field and refocuses it
        this.password.setValue(null);
        this.password.focus();

    }
}
```

2) Main View is as below:

`public class MainView extends CustomComponent implements View {`

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final String NAME = "";

Label text = new Label();

Button logout = new Button("Logout", new Button.ClickListener() {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

        // "Logout" the user
        getSession().setAttribute("user", null);

        // Refresh this view, should redirect to login view
        getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(NAME);
    }
});

public MainView() {
    setCompositionRoot(new CssLayout(text, logout));
}

@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
    // Get the user name from the session
    String username = String.valueOf(getSession().getAttribute("user"));

    // And show the username
    text.setValue("Hello " + username);
}
```

}

3) A main class which navigates between above 2 view

`public class LoginUI extends UI {`

```
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = LoginUI.class)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    //
    // Create a new instance of the navigator. The navigator will attach
    // itself automatically to this view.
    //
    new Navigator(this, this);

    //
    // The initial log view where the user can login to the application
    //
    getNavigator().addView(SimpleLoginView.NAME, SimpleLoginView.class);//

    //
    // Add the main view of the application
    //
    getNavigator().addView(MainView.NAME,
            MainView.class);

    //
    // We use a view change handler to ensure the user is always redirected
    // to the login view if the user is not logged in.
    //
    getNavigator().addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {

            // Check if a user has logged in
            boolean isLoggedIn = getSession().getAttribute("user") != null;
            boolean isLoginView = event.getNewView() instanceof SimpleLoginView;

            if (!isLoggedIn && !isLoginView) {
                // Redirect to login view always if a user has not yet
                // logged in
                getNavigator().navigateTo(SimpleLoginView.NAME);
                return false;

            } else if (isLoggedIn && isLoginView) {
                // If someone tries to access to login view while logged in,
                // then cancel
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

While running the code in the Tomcat I am getting below error:

`    `type Exception report`

```
message com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException:       java.lang.InstantiationException
```

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:307)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1460)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1414)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException
    com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator$ClassBasedViewProvider.getView(Navigator.java:340)
    com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:512)
    com.example.login.LoginUI$1.beforeViewChange(LoginUI.java:58)
    com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.fireBeforeViewChange(Navigator.java:595)
    com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:553)
    com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:526)
    com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:644)
    com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:222)
    com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1402)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.InstantiationException
    sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator$ClassBasedViewProvider.getView(Navigator.java:336)
    com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:512)
    com.example.login.LoginUI$1.beforeViewChange(LoginUI.java:58)
    com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.fireBeforeViewChange(Navigator.java:595)
    com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:553)
    com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:526)
    com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:644)
    com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:222)
    com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1402)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.55 logs.

---

`

Comment: You should reformat your question so that it can be properly read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaadin's Navigator class tries to instantiate its view classes by reflection if the views are added to the navigator via `Navigator#addView(String viewName, Class<? extends View> viewClass)`. But in your case, class `SimpleLoginView` can't be instantiated because you declared it `abstract`. Remove the classifier `abstract` from your view class defintion and your example should work.

Comment: One Question, In the SimpleLoginView.java there is a line as below

viewLayout.setStyleName(Reindeer.LAYOUT_BLUE);

I believe this should set the backgriound color to Blue, but currently it is not doing so. It comes without any background color.
Please let me know how to achieve it?

Comment: For changing the look and feel of your Vaadin application, I'd advise you to have a look at Vaadin themes: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html This is too broad a topic as to be dealt with in a comment :)